# Unable to create reactive form with this nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I am trying to create a reactive form with a complex data structure which is doing a lot of things and I would like your help on how to create it. So basically this is the structure of the data I have which I want to use:

```
[
  {
     type: 'body',
     items: [
        {
           type: 'text',
           id: 1,
           value: '',
           isCustom: false,
           customValue: '' 
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

In `items` array, there could be 0 or a million items. So if there is at least one, I want to show fields in the template.

So basically there are two fields for each item. One `select box` and another is an `input` field. The select box will have some items, let's just say some options. All of the options are predefined and when one of them is selected the `value` field in `items` object gets stored in. In `select box` options, there is one option which is `Custom`. When that is selected, the `value` field is set to `custom`, `isCustom` is set to true and the `input` field shows up. When something is typed in the `input` field, the `customValue` field is where it is stored in. This is the basic functionality.

Now I can do everything from updating and storing and validation, etc. Except I am unable to do the very first thing which is setup the `form control`. I think I have to use Angular's `FormArray` here but I am now sure how.

All I need from you is a bare mininum of how to create this `form control` based on the data structure I have provided. Because of not able to do this I moved away from Reactive Forms to template-driven forms, which is giving me a headache with the validations.

This is what I tried so far:

TS file:

```
private formBuilder = new FormBuilder();

form = this.formBuilder.group({
    title: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [
        Validators.required,
        FormValidator.nonWhitespace,
        Validators.maxLength(80),
      ],
    }),
    body: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});

ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.bodyArray.controls.length === 0) {
      this.addBodyItem();
    }
}

get bodyArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('body') as FormArray;
}

createBodyItem(): FormGroup {
    // no idea what to do here    
}

addBodyItem(): void {
    this.bodyArray.push(this.createBodyItem());
}
```

Template File:

```
<div formArrayName="body">

   // no idea what to loop here

</div>
```

Please note that I am using the same component for both create and edit mode. So for edit mode I think the `form controls` need  to be created in `ngOnInit` to show the fields.

It would be really big help if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Where is this `this.bodyArray` coming from?

Comment: The getter function.

Comment: So you are trying to dyanamically populate the controls and there validators?

Comment: Yes based on the data.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-rows-dynamically-formgroup-formarray-b9pjd4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html check this link if this example has been added with your case would it make sense?

Comment: That link shows almost what I have right now. I need to know which fields I need to put in `createBodyItem` method to create the form groups.

Comment: What you need to do is push from controls the array depending upon your array.

Comment: Something similar to this  `createNItem(){
    this.form.addControl('new', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
  }`

Comment: Yes, but which fields should I add there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254509/discussion-between-selakan-and-s-khan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Posting this for anyone's reference. The below code sample generates form controls dynamically while iterating through the array of items provided and properties based on it.**

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  myForm: FormGroup;
  formControls = [
    { type: 'input', label: 'Name', name: 'name', inputType: 'text' },
    { type: 'input', label: 'Email', name: 'email', inputType: 'email' },
    { type: 'select', label: 'Country', name: 'country', options: [
        { label: 'United States', value: 'US' },
        { label: 'Canada', value: 'CA' },
        { label: 'Mexico', value: 'MX' }
      ]
    }
    // Add more form controls as needed
  ];
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
    this.formControls.forEach(control => {
      const formControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required); // Create form control
      this.myForm.addControl(control.name, formControl); // Add controls to myForm
    });
  }
 
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let control of formControls">
    <div [ngSwitch]="control.type">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'input'">
        <label>{{ control.label }}</label>
        <input [formControlName]="control.name" [type]="control.inputType">
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
        <label>{{ control.label }}</label>
        <select [formControlName]="control.name">
          <option *ngFor="let option of control.options" [value]="option.value">{{ option.label }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- Add more cases for other control types as needed -->
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

**Refer sample working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-rows-dynamically-formgroup-formarray-b9pjd4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed this and it is working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help :) Nice chatting with you..